# Mongoose .save with vs without callback, AND .disconnect vs .close

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

In trying to seed some mock data, I noticed that .save with callback doesn't work while .save without callback does work.
With callback returns: "MongoError: Topology is closed, please connect"

Also, .close() does work while .disconnect() does not work.
.disconnect() returns: "TypeError: mongoose.connection.disconnect is not a function"

I'd like to know why both of these errors occur and what I need to change in the code to make them work. What are the missing pieces to make them functional?

----**START UPDATE**----

Found out the the disconnect() function is from version 4 of Mongoose, and I'm using version 5.

The save() function with callback is still unresolved.

----**END UPDATE**----

Here's the github to the project: https://github.com/yanichik/hockey-camp

Here's my code with the working solutions commented out (file name: index-seeds.js):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Camp = require('../models/camp');
const picsArray = require('./pics-seeds');

/*START MONGOOSE SETUP*/
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/hockey-camp', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
});

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
    console.log("Mongoose connected")
});
/*END MONGOOSE SETUP*/

/*START INSERT ONE*/
// const minnesota = new Camp({name: 'Minnesota Hockey Camps'});
// minnesota.save( function(err, minnesota){
//  if (err) {
//      return console.log(err);
//  }
// });
/*END INSERT ONE*/

/*START SEED*/
const seedCamps = async () =>{
    const picsSize = picsArray.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < picsSize; i++){
        const newCamp = new Camp({pics: picsArray[i].pic});

        /* THIS SAVE METHOD RETURNS "MongoError: Topology is closed, please connect" */
        await newCamp.save(function(e, someCamp){
            if(e) return console.log("Something went wrong :(" + e);
            console.log(`Successfully added ${someCamp}`);
        })

        /* this save method works without fault */
        // await newCamp.save();
    }
}

/* this close method works without fault */
/*seedCamps().then(() => {
    mongoose.connection.close();
})
.catch(e => {console.log(e)})*/

/* THIS DISCONNECT METHOD RETURNS "TypeError: mongoose.connection.disconnect is not a function" */
seedCamps().then(() => {
    mongoose.connection.disconnect();
})
.catch(e => {console.log(e)})

/*END SEED*/
```